# How i can remove the empty cells from my table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using custom cells for table view and as per my code if no condition met it adds an empty cell or row in my table view. i'm new on iOS please help me in removing empty cells. here is my code snippet.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let dict1 = arrMsg.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ChatTableViewCell
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2") as! Chat2TableViewCell

        if((String(describing: dict1.object(forKey: "SenderId")!)) == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid && (ChatVC.selectedUser.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "") == (String(describing: dict1.object(forKey: "ReceiverId")!))))
        {
            cell2.lblSender.text = (dict1.object(forKey: "Message") as! String)
            cell2.lblSender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.09, green: 0.54, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            cell2.lblSender.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell2.lblSender.textColor = .white
            cell2.lblSender?.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell2.lblSender.layer.cornerRadius = 7
            return cell2
        }
        else if ((String(describing: dict1.object(forKey: "ReceiverId")!)) == (Auth.auth().currentUser!.email?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))!)
        {
            cell.lblReceiver.text = (dict1.object(forKey: "Message") as! String)
            cell.lblReceiver.backgroundColor = UIColor .lightGray
            cell.lblReceiver.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell.lblReceiver.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.lblReceiver?.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.lblReceiver.layer.cornerRadius = 7
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Basically, you should handle the used data source (array/dictionary) before even returning the cell, it should be reflected on `numberForRows` therefore the cell will get returned...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something that should be cleared up by your [TableView's DataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) instead of you having to handle the logic of whether something exists or not in `cellForRowAt`.  You should be able to add logic to find the number of rows in each section/how many sections there are based upon your `arrMsg` object

Comment: arrMsg has 2 sections. 1 includes sender and receiver details and 2nd is the message

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let dict1 = arrMsg.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [String:Any]
    let str = dict1["SenderId"] as! String
    if str == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid { 
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2") as! Chat2TableViewCell
        cell2.lblSender.text = (dict1.object(forKey: "Message") as! String)
        cell2.lblSender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.09, green: 0.54, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        cell2.lblSender.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        cell2.lblSender.textColor = .white
        cell2.lblSender?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell2.lblSender.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        return cell2
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ChatTableViewCell
        cell.lblReceiver.text = (dict1.object(forKey: "Message") as! String)
        cell.lblReceiver.backgroundColor = UIColor .lightGray
        cell.lblReceiver.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        cell.lblReceiver.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.lblReceiver?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.lblReceiver.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        return cell
    }

}
```

it's your job to make sure that senderID should be the current user or the sending user , but not nil which will lead to returning the empty cell , also don't use `NS` stuff in Swift

Comment: it is just like a messaging app. im using firebase and i have a single node to handle all users messages based on sender id and receiver id thats why i did that. no the problem is if a message has sender id which is not current user and receiver id is also not the user who is receiving then in that case it add empty cell according to my code

Comment: **message has sender id which is not current user and receiver id is also not the user who is receiving**

Comment: this is not possible the current user should be either the sender or a receiver

Answer (score 0):

go to story board select your tableview in the inspect change separator style from default or whatever to none